# Reference for $f \in L^{p,\infty} \cap L^{q}$ then $f \in L^r$ for $p < r \leq q$

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis, reference-request, lp-spaces, integral-inequality

Okay, so I think I've shown that if $f \in L^{p,\infty} \cap L^{q}$ with $p < q$ then $f \in L^r$ for $p < r \leq q$ where $L^{p, \infty}$ denotes the weak $L^p$ space. what I did was I wrote
$$ \int_{\mathbb{R}^n} |f|^r dx = r \int_0^{\infty} t^{r-1} \lambda_f(t)dt =  r \int_0^{1} t^{r-1}\lambda_f(t)dt + r \int_1^{\infty} t^{r-1} \lambda_f(t)dt   $$
$$\leq r \int_0^{1} t^{r-1} \lambda_f(t)dt +   r\int_1^{\infty} t^{q-1} \lambda_f(t)dt $$ 
and to bound the first term I use estimate on $\lambda_f(t)$ given by $L^{p,\infty}$ assumption while the second one is just a part of formula for $||f||_q$. My question is - does this result have a name? It seems like something that should come up relatively often and I don't want to bother the readers of what I'm writing with an obsolete proof. I looked for names like weak Holder inequality but all I got was a more general claim that isn't true in fact. (I thought it might be called that cause if we had strong $L^p$ we could show our claim using Holder)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's the *interpolation property of weak Lebesgue spaces*. It  can be refined to 
$$ \| u \|_{L^{r}} \leq C_{p,q,r} \| u \|_{L^{p,\infty}}^{\alpha} \| u \|_{L^{q,\infty}}^{1 - \alpha} $$
where $p<r<q$ and
$$ \frac{1}{r} = \frac{\alpha}{p} + \frac{1 - \alpha}{q}$$
See [this blog post](https://dochunosei.wordpress.com/2013/02/17/strong-and-weak-lebesgue-spaces-lorentz-spaces-and-orlicz-spaces/) or [that blog post](http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2009/03/30/245c-notes-1-interpolation-of-lp-spaces/).

Or if you prefer books: *Interpolation of Operators* by Bennett and Sharpley, or *Classical Fourier Analysis* by Grafakos.